# Why does Safari fail percentage decimals in width, does Safari round the number up/down?

Tags: html, css, safari, width, percentage

I have a wrapper there has a width:100%; and 7 items boxes inside that wrapper there has a width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;

```
wrapper{     
width: 100%;
}

items{
width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
}
```

It works perfectly with Opera, Chrome, Firefox and Explorer but with Safari it looks like in my case that Safari rounds down the number so i get a gap at the end of the items boxes.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Yes, all kinds of calculations are taking place in every browser and I doubt there's a spec for when the rounding should occur.  In any case, I don't think anyone could reasonably expect CSS rendering to be accurate to 30 decimal places.  My workaround would make the seven items `14%` each with a `1%` spacer on both ends, or a `98%` total width that's centered.

Comment: Have you tried with box-sizing: border-box ? like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjVLLR

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle or post a live URL? I can't seem to recreate the issue.

Comment: Ok thank you all, but i found out why, it is because i use safari on my windows computer if i use safari on a mac pc it works!